# ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'FileStorage'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I just want to write a filename from data to my model.
How to get filename from filestorage?

I'm using Flask for my web app. I create form that include FileField.
It is important for me to get the same filename.

Form:

```py
class TableForm(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField('Add file', validators=[FileAllowed(['xlsx', 'xls', 'csv'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Add file')
```

Model:

```py
class Table(db.Model):
    __table_args__= {'schema': 'app'}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(240), nullable=False)
    table_file = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
```

Routes:

```py
@app.route("/projects/<int:project_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def project_data_source(project_id):
    tables = Table.query.filter_by(project_id=project_id)
    if project.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    form = TableForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        table = Table(name=form.file.data, table_file=form.file.data)
        db.session.add(table)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('project_data_source'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty good example on [their docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html). Here's how you get the file name:

```py
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

f = form.file.data
filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
```

So your code would need to be:

```py
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


@app.route("/projects/<int:project_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def project_data_source(project_id):
    tables = Table.query.filter_by(project_id=project_id)
    if project.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    form = TableForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        filename = secure_filename(form.file.data.filename)
        table = Table(name=filename, table_file=filename)  # not sure why you save it twice here
        db.session.add(table)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('project_data_source'))
```